# Vaadin Grid TextField for Boolean StringToBooleanConverter

Tags: java, vaadin

While working on an in-line editing feature in Vaadin Grid (8.1.0), I have created the beans and use setItems method from the Grid to populate all rows.

But when I double clicked a row to edit it, an exception came up. I thought I have bound the bean's property type correctly with the TextField but it still throws exception.

The following is my manual binding code that finds a Boolean property to the Textfield I like to use for editing.

```
    Binder<RegistrationRecord> needFancialFlagBinder = new Binder<>(RegistrationRecord.class);
    needFancialFlagBinder .forField ( needFancialFlagField ) 
      .withNullRepresentation( "" )
      .withConverter (new StringToBooleanConverter("Need financial flag must be true or false!"))
      .bind ( RegistrationRecord:: isNeedFancialFlag, RegistrationRecord:: setNeedFancialFlag);
```

The following code attaches the TextField with the column in the Grid.

```
    registrationGrid.getColumn("needFancialFlag")
    .setEditorComponent(needFancialFlagField)   
    .setExpandRatio(1);
```

Below is part of the exception. Does the StringToBooleanConverter only take care of converting from String to Boolean and not the other way around? What method should I be using for the other direction?

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractTextField.setValue(AbstractTextField.java:47) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at com.vaadin.data.Binder$BindingImpl.initFieldValue(Binder.java:893) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at com.vaadin.data.Binder$BindingImpl.access$100(Binder.java:766) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at com.vaadin.data.Binder.lambda$readBean$2(Binder.java:1386) ~[vaadin-server-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
```

Comment: Still working on it...

Comment: You need this the other way around.  If you have Boolean in your Model and want to use a TextField to represent it, you need to write a BooleanToStringConverter.  But why not just use a CheckBox and be done with it?

Comment: Hi cfrick - That's a great idea. I will go ahead and implement CheckBox, which is the right way. I was just not that experienced with the inline editor. Thanks again. I did try to write a new Converter and the exception got turned around which is annoying. But I will proceed with CheckBox. Thanks again!

Comment: Now I have modified the editor to be a CheckBox. However the display now says "true" or "false" and only when I click on the row it becomes a check box. Does this mean I need to give it a CustomRenderer so it knows how to render this column?

Comment: Yes, you need a `Renderer` for tha column too. I thought vaadin nowadays already brings one to render booleans to some nice UTF-8 chars, but i was wrong.  So either that, or a HTML Renderer, that renders to VaadinIcon spans.

Comment: There are something needing more studies. With this line of code aColumn.setRenderer(new HtmlRenderer());     it gave me an error saying The method setRenderer(Renderer<? super capture#12-of ?>) in the type Grid.Column<RegistrationRecord,capture#12-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (HtmlRenderer).

Comment: I did the following HtmlRenderer and it is working pretty well for display purpose. Column<RegistrationRecord, String> htmlColumn = registrationGrid.addColumn(record ->
        "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"adultFlag\" " + returnChecked(record) + ">",
       new HtmlRenderer());
  registrationGrid.getColumn("adultFlag")
        .setEditorComponent(adultFlagCheckBox) 
        .set xpandRatio(1);
    Thing is - do I need to set a ValueChangeListener? It seems the editor checkbox is not in force any more.

Comment: Sorry to maybe mislead you.  But this has turned in one of this "i did this but now..."-cascades. Please phrase what exactly you want to have and what you have tried in your question -- or, if the original question basically _is_ answered, create a new one and reference it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the question was asked inadequately. I wanted to use a TextField to edit a Boolean model member in a column of a Grid and somewhere in the process, a better idea was proposed. Instead of using a TextField, I should have used a CheckBox. So, the solution got turned around, and below is the correct code. Note this is Vaadin 8.1.0. (I found Vaadin has changed a lot of versions quickly.)

```
    private void addBooleanPropertyColumn(Grid theGrid, String propertyName, String caption) {
    CheckBox bBox = new CheckBox();  
    Column<RegistrationRecord, String> adultFlagColumn = theGrid.addColumn(record->
        "<span class=\"v-checkbox v-widget\"><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"my-uid-1\" " + returnChecked(propertyName, record) + "  > <label for=\"my-uid-1\"></label> </span>",
        new HtmlRenderer());
    adultFlagColumn.setId(propertyName)
    .setCaption(caption)
    .setEditorComponent(bBox) 
    .setExpandRatio(1); 
}
```

The concept is that a Column in a Grid supports the association of a Renderer, a Validator, and an Editor. Once you have learned that, it becomes straightforward.

I am not using a Validator since the model field is only a Boolean. And it is worth noting the editor component must have an associated property, hence the setID, a convenient setter.